# Why does JUnit platform error appear when running a single test?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

An error is thrown when running a single test:
`Failed to resolve org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.7.0`

The test is launched by clicking on the button in the form of a green triangle next to the name of the method.

But if you run testing of the whole project through maven (lifecycle -> test), then such an error is not visible, and all tests work quietly.

To use JUnit, this dependency is used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The rest of the team who work on this project (one repository, different branches) do not have such problems. What can be causing this error? IDE used - IntelliJ IDEA

**UPD:** I've tried everything. Deleting the .idea folder had no effect, nor did re-downloading all dependencies. Clearing the cache also had no effect

**UPD 2:** Proxy is already specified

Comment: Seems like IDE didn't import the dependency from Maven. Try re-importing Maven project.

Comment: Network issue... reload configuration in IDE ... or clear the cache and delete `.idea` and reimport ...

Comment: Once network connectivity is established, check the local repository. If the download failed, there could be a corrupt file. Delete the artifact folder.

Comment: But how does the tests that run in the whole project work (Lifecycle - test)? If there was a problem with the library, then most likely they would not work at all

Comment: Had the same ...
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003256319-Exception-intellij-failed-to-resolve-org-junit-platform-junit-platform-launcher-1-3-2

Comment: If you use proxies or custom Maven repositories - make sure you configure them in  Maven `settings.xml` file properly. The repositories IDE uses for downloading the Junit launcher (needed to run the JUnit tests) are located under Settings(Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | **Remote Jar Repositories**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by manually adding JUnit Platform Launcher files to the local repository. This is probably not the optimal solution, but it worked for me

Comment: Do you mean the m2 folder? I have the dependency there but still getting this error in intellij 2023.1